# Why does imakeidx + nonewpage fail to write an idx file?

Tags: page-breaking, indexing, imakeidx

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

stuff\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

When I run `lualatex` on this file, I see among the output on stdout:

```
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
\indexentry{test}{1}
] (./mwe.aux) )
```

The `\indexentry` seems to be written to stdout rather than to the `.idx` file--the `.idx` file ends up empty, and thus I get no index at all.

If I remove the `nonewpage` option to imakeidx the `.idx` file gets built as I expected.  Alternatively, adding a `\clearpage` before `\printindex` also makes things work as expected.

What's going on here?  I was just trying to remove the page break before my index!

FWIW I'm on MacTeX 2013, and I just ran the TeX Live updater yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid it's a bug in `imakeidx` which calls for closing the `idx` file too early even if `noautomatic` (implied by `nonewpage`) is in force.

For the moment you can give the correct definition to `\imki@putindex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\makeatletter
\def\imki@putindex#1{%
  \ifimki@nonewpage\else
    \imki@clearpage
%%% The following two lines are incorrectly switched in the package
    \immediate\closeout\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname
  \fi
  \let\imki@indexname\indexname % keep \indexname
  \@nameuse{imki@set@#1}\imki@decide
  \if@tempswa % we can call the external program
    \imki@exec{\imki@program\imki@options#1.idx}%
  \else
    \imki@finalmessage{#1}%
  \fi
  \ifKV@imki@intoc
    \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{\@nameuse{phantomsection}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{\imki@toclevel}{\imki@title}}%
  \else
    \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{}%
  \fi
  \ifx\imki@title\imki@check@indexname\else
    \def\indexname{\imki@title}%
  \fi
  \@input@{#1.ind}
  \let\indexname\imki@indexname % restore \indexname
}
\makeatother
\makeindex

\begin{document}

stuff\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

A fixed version of the package is on its way to CTAN.

Comment: @dsedivec Sorry for the bug. ;-)

Comment: Seems as if this bug is back in TeXLive 2019.

Comment: I updated all packages and problem still remains. The workaround in the answer no longer solves the problem, nor does adding a `\clearpage` (as mentioned in the question) before `\printindex`.