# Index at the beginning of a document

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

Is it possible to insert an index at the beginning of a document, like so?:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[name=definitions,title=Definitions,columns=1,intoc=true,program=makeindex,options={-s index_style.ist}]

\begin{document}
\printindex[definitions]

bla bla \index[definitions]{bla}, lorem ipsum \index[definitions]{ipsum}

\end{document}
```

FYI the content of index_style.ist is:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\large\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

Comment: You can't have the automatically generated index at the beginning; for this you need to pass the `noautomatic` option and run `makeindex` manually.

Comment: Is there a way to automate the process?

Comment: With `arara`, certainly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `imakeidx` with the `nonewpage` option and run `makeindex` manually.

Unfortunately, there's also the need to apply a patch around a bug that should be solved in the next release of `imakeidx`; see [Why does imakeidx + nonewpage fail to write an idx file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133193/why-does-imakeidx-nonewpage-fail-to-write-an-idx-file)

In order to automate the work you have two roads:

1. Use `latexmk`
2. Use `arara`

I'd prefer the latter, as it's more easily customizable.

Example (thanks to Paulo Cereda, `arara`'s author, for suggesting the `files` trick).

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex: { files: [definitions], style: index_style.ist}
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}

% work around the bug. :(
\makeatletter
\def\imki@putindex#1{%
  \ifimki@nonewpage\else
    \imki@clearpage
%%% The following two lines are incorrectly switched in the package
    \immediate\closeout\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname
  \fi
  \let\imki@indexname\indexname % keep \indexname
  \@nameuse{imki@set@#1}\imki@decide
  \if@tempswa % we can call the external program
    \imki@exec{\imki@program\imki@options#1.idx}%
  \else
    \imki@finalmessage{#1}%
  \fi
  \ifKV@imki@intoc
    \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{\@nameuse{phantomsection}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{\imki@toclevel}{\imki@title}}%
  \else
    \def\imki@maybeaddtotoc{}%
  \fi
  \ifx\imki@title\imki@check@indexname\else
    \def\indexname{\imki@title}%
  \fi
  \@input@{#1.ind}
  \let\indexname\imki@indexname % restore \indexname
}
\makeatother
%%% end of bug fix

%\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[name=definitions,
  title=Definitions,
  columns=1,
  intoc=true,
  program=makeindex,
  options={-s index_style.ist}]

\begin{document}
\printindex[definitions]

bla bla \index[definitions]{bla}, lorem ipsum \index[definitions]{ipsum}

\end{document}
```

If you run `arara -v filename`, you'll get this output.

[image]

There is a reason for the standard `imakeidx` automation not being possible in this case: in order to run `makeindex`, the `.idx` file(s) must be closed and contain all the required entries, which is not possible if the indices are not at the end of the document. The `.idx` files written during the previous run are not available any more, because the `\makeindex` declaration opens them (emptying them as a consequence) at begin document.

Also

```
latexmk filename
```

should work out of the box (with the patch).

Comment: When will the patch be available on CTAN?

Comment: @idle Soon, sure.